# Replacing fixed size substrings in front of known pattern

Tags: python, string, substring

I have the following problem:

1. I have a very long string (length of string = 54883508)
2. I need to replace all sub-strings in a very short time

The string contains stuff following this pattern:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCCaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCCaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCCaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCCaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCCaaXXXXXXXXXCCaXXXXXXXXXCCaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCC
```

I need to replace `XXXXXXXXXCC` but the only thing I know is the position of `CC` as `XXXXXXXXX` is dynamic and random.

Any idea?

Comment: check python re module

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't know how to replace XXXXXXXXXCC when I only know the position of CC nither what is in XXXXXXXXX or CC.

Comment: @Vinny I did but I can not use or find an appropriate example

Comment: Do you know the number of chars before CC? or the separator?

Comment: @Vinny I know only what is the position CC and number of chars of XXXXXXXXX

Comment: Can you show a concrete example string? (Or part of it if it is very long)

Comment: How do you define "very short time"? Do you have a solution that works but is too slow? It would be helpful to get an answer if you showed that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The string is way to long

Comment: @mkrieger1 minutes will work

Comment: Please consider to explain better your problem and add an example because it is not fully understandble right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `re.sub` function you can do this

```
import re 
data = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCCaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCCaaaaa  aaaaXXXXXXXXXCCaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCCaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCCaaXXXXXXXXXCCaXXXXXXXXXCCaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXCC'

print re.sub('(?<=XXXXXXXXX)CC', '11', data)
```

This will change `CC` to `11`. The pattern defined by `(?<=XXXXX)CC` means **match CC only if preceded by XXXXX**, otherwise don't. If you don't know the pattern, but know the number of chars you can use `(?<=\w{9})CC` to match any 9 characters ahead.

Comment: I don't think the string *literally* contains `CC` or `XXXX...`. That's why I asked for an actual example.

Comment: So you change `CC` to what you look for, and XXX with another regex pattern such as `\w`